# Modifying existing regular expression to retrieve the index

Tags: html, regex, excel, vba

I have an html and there are few indexes present. Sample is below

```
this is first sample index <!-- @@struct1_s§var1-->19.5.1<!--Index--> and this is required

this is second sample index <!-- @@struct2_s§var2-->19.5.2<!--Index--> - this is extension to the sample index <!-- @@struct3_s§var3-->19.5.3<!--Index--> and this is required.
```

I use the regular expression

```
"<!--\s?@{2}[\.\w]*§[\.\w\[.\]]+-->[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+<!--Index-->"
```

so if at all I parse the above part of html I will get the matches as

```
<!-- @@struct1_s§var1-->19.5.1<!--Index-->
<!-- @@struct2_s§var2-->19.5.2<!--Index-->
<!-- @@struct3_s§var3-->19.5.3<!--Index-->
```

now I want to change my regular expression such that if at all - exists I want to retrieve the entire index

So if at all I parse the above part of html I should get the matched as

```
<!-- @@struct1_s§var1-->19.5.1<!--Index-->
<!-- @@struct2_s§var2-->19.5.2<!--Index--> - <!-- @@struct3_s§var3-->19.5.3<!--Index-->
```

I am trying to use this expression but it will also retrieve other characters present in the same line

```
regEx.Pattern = "<!--\s?@{2}[\.\w]*§[\.\w\[.\]]+-->[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+<!--Index-->[-\s?]?[<!--\s?@{2}[\.\w]*§[\.\w\[.\]]+-->[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+<!--Index-->]?"
```

If somebody can help me with this please.

Comment: `<!--.*<!--Index-->`

Comment: vks can you give me the entire expression please

Comment: its not appearing. maybe u need to put them between flower braces

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version can do it in three matches; it does what you want for the above test case:

```
<!--\s?@{2}[\.\w]*§[\.\w\[.\]]+-->\d+\.\d+\.\d+<!--Index-->( - )?
```

You can do what you want in two matches, but you will have to match more than what you want and then use the first and second capturing groups to get the matching parts you want (usually $1 and $2).

```
(<!--\s?@{2}[\.\w]*§[\.\w\[.\]]+-->\d+\.\d+\.\d+<!--Index-->(?: - )?)(?:.*(<!--\s?@{2}[\.\w]*§[\.\w\[.\]]+-->\d+\.\d+\.\d+<!--Index-->))?
```

The first one is preferable if you can make it work.